# What does the WEB_ROOT in a Rails' app's .env do/how is it used?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

I see `WEB_ROOT=localhost:3001` in my `.env` file but don't know how Rails uses this variable because I didn't find anything when I did a fuzzy search for it. Does `puma` or something else somehow finds this variable behind the scenes?